# Keystore is not initialized exception

Tags: java, android, keystore

This my code used for usage of key store.While I am running my app it is showing an exception that key store is not initialized.

```
                 try {
                        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                        pk = ks.getKey("Alias", null);
                        if(pk != null){
                            sendSMS("5556", Base64.encodeToString(pk.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                        }

                    }
                    catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


          try {
                    ks.deleteEntry("Alias");
                    ks.setKeyEntry("Alias", privateKey.getEncoded(), null);
                }
                catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the variable 'ks' out of scope. The lines

```
ks.deleteEntry("Alias");
ks.setKeyEntry("Alias", privateKey.getEncoded(), null);
```

need to be in the same `try{` block as `KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");`

You also need to initialize the keystore, by using the `load(..)` method: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html#load(java.io.InputStream, char[])

Using your example code, that would be:

```
try {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(null, null);
    pk = ks.getKey("Alias", null);
    if(pk != null){
        sendSMS("5556", Base64.encodeToString(pk.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
    ks.deleteEntry("Alias");
    ks.setKeyEntry("Alias", privateKey.getEncoded(), null);
}
catch (KeyStoreException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: same as i said above: keystore was not initialized

Comment: Do you get the error when compiling (building the APK) or when running the APK on your device/emulator?

Comment: no error only exception while running in the emulator and observed that in logcat

Comment: I updated the code to include the load(..) call to initialize the keystore.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ks` is a local variable declared in a try block. This makes it local to that try itself and inaccessible to any other *outer* block.

Change,

```
try {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
```

To,

```
KeyStore ks;
try {
     ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
```

This would avoid pushing `ks` out of scope when your first try block ends.

Comment: Is there any other block where you reference to `ks`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:
 `ks.load(null)` ?

That will initialize the keystore with the default values.
That should be enough for your example.